# How to split commons js in next without dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have a file in my project that has several `export ASSET_NAME = require('/assets/myAsset.png')` exports like this, I use it for some ui bits that I want to use `url-loader` on in order to base64 these asset images.

I then use this file in various pages of my project i.e `import { ASSET_NAME } from "./assets.js"`

After inspecting my built project I can see that all these base64 strings are located in my `commons.js` file. Ideally I'd want this file to be it's own something like `assets.js` so it can load in parallel with `commons.js`. After reading the doc's only method I saw to do this was via [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-import), however I don't want to await this file nor load it when user makes certain action, I just want it to be separate file loaded to my page in parallel / separate from commons,js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a new `splitChunk` in your `next.config.js` file.

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.assetsChunk = {
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true,
        minChunks: 1,
        name: 'assets-chunk',
        priority: 10,
        test: /[\\\/]path-to-your-asset[\\\/]/,
      };
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

Just replace `path-to-your-asset` to the import path (or some of it as it is a regex).

For more info read [splitChunks docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

Comment: Any chance you could expand on why client check is needed here? `!options.isServer`

Comment: Usually chunk splitting doesn't have any affect on server side, if you wanna apply it for the server (why?), you can remove this check :]

Comment: You know how I could limit the number of chunks to no more than 3, I'm having a lot of trouble with the google bot.